# "afraid to miss" or "afraid of missing"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> Afraid as an adjective means ‘feeling fear’. We use it with of + noun, of + -ing form, a to-infinitive or a that-clause [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives/afraid)

We can use *of +ing* or *to-infinitive* with *afraid*, how to know what we should use?

Which one of the following is correct? what is the difference in meaning between them?

> - I hurried to the station. I was **afraid to miss** my train.
> - I hurried to the station. I was **afraid of missing** my train.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereas ***afraid to do something*** describes the feeling of fear (or uncertainty) about something you are on the point of doing:

> She was afraid to say what she really meant,

***afraid of doing something*** talks in much more general terms of this fear that applies to any time or situation:

> Some old people are afraid of walking alone at night in the dark.

So, in the situation of feeling fear about possibility of missing a train,  it would be

> I hurried to the station. I was afraid to miss my train.

[The source](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic2812.html).

Comment: Here’s the way I’d probably word it: _I was afraid **I’d** miss my train_.